# Get attribute from parent resource in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have an model, `userhashtag`, that belongs to `hashtag` (ie one-many).  As its name suggests, the `userhashtag` model links the `user` model with the `hashtag` model.

The `userhashtag` model only contains the **user_id** and the **hashtag_id**.  I have an ember template that lists all of the userhashtags for a certain **user_id**, and I want to display the userhashtags with the **name** attribute, contained in its parent, the hashtag model.

Here is my userhashtag model:

```
App.Userhashtag = DS.Model.extend({
userId: DS.attr('number'),
hashtagId: DS.attr('number'),
createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
updatedAt: DS.attr('date'),
user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
hashtag: DS.belongsTo('hashtag'),
hashtagname: function(){
    var h = this.store.find('hashtag', this.get('hashtagId'));
    return h.get('name');
}.property('hashtagId')
});
```

And I'm trying to call it in my template like this:

```
{{userhashtag.hashtagname}}
```

I'm using the ember extension for chrome developer tools, and I can see that it is correctly loading all the `hashtags` and `userhashtags`.  However, I still don't see the name attribute.  Upon inspection, the store is correctly finding the corresponding hashtag, but the `var h` is returning as undefined.

Would anyone have any suggestions on why the `hashtagname` function isn't returning the name?  Also, I feel like I'm not doing this in best practice, what should I be doing instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you show us what json is coming down from your request?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, h should be a promise, not a record.

Secondly, does hashTag belongsTo work?

```
hashtagname: function(){
   return this.get('hashtag.name');
}.property('hashtag')
```

At the same time in the template you could just as easily do

```
{{hashtag.name}}
```

You shouldn't be using the store inside of a model, I'm not even positive how you did that without injecting the store into everything. (I'm intrigued for kicks and giggles you should post it)

Comment: No, the belongsTo doesn't work.  According to the ember chrome extension userhashtag.hashtag is null.  I didn't realize that calling the store in the model wasn't a good idea, maybe that's why it isn't working (although it DOES get the hashtag models).
What is a promise?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `hastagId` and userId from your model. When ember-data tries to parse the model and finds a `somemodel_id` and also a `belongsTo` with the same name (without `_id`) it then also loads the `belongsTo` (or it loads, when some properties of it are needed, if I remember correct).